# Which part of the CheckedTextView was clicked?

Tags: android

A checkedTextView shows a text box and a checkbox.

Is it possible for code to determine if only the checkbox part was clicked?

If so, the code could respond differently the user clicking the checkbox or the text view.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't know which part has been clicked, judging by the [CheckedTextView source code](http://www.netmite.com/android/mydroid/cupcake/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/CheckedTextView.java) as the CheckedTextView is one view. However you can create your own by betting ideas in the source...